# How to trigger init of a controller when loading different template in a modal - angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I know there is [angular bootstarp modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/modal) but for now I have a modal which is opened using `$('#msg-modal').modal();`

I have created modal as :

```
<div class="modal signUpContent fade" id="msg-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top: 200px;">
    <div class="modal-content" ng-style="modal_data.style.container">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background: #0bb586;" ng-style="modal_data.style.header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>
            <h3 class="modal-title-site text-center"> {{ modal_data.title }} </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <center ng-if="!(modal_data.template)"><span compile="modal_data.msg"></span></center>
            <span ng-if="(modal_data.template)">
                <div ng-include="modal_data.template"></div>
            </span>
            <hr>
            <center>
                <a ng-style="modal_data.style.ok_btn" ng-click="buttonClick(modal_data.ok_btn.on_click)" class="btn btn-primary smooth-corner" ng-show="modal_data.ok_btn" ng-href="{{ modal_data.ok_btn.path }}" ng-bind="modal_data.ok_btn.name"> </a>
                <a ng-style="modal_data.style.cancel_btn" ng-click="buttonClick(modal_data.cancel_btn.on_click)" class="btn btn-primary smooth-corner" ng-show="modal_data.cancel_btn" ng-bind="modal_data.cancel_btn.name"></a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

as you can see I have `<div ng-include="modal_data.template"></div>` which loads a template when passed to it. The issue is that if I assign a controller inside that `modal_data.template` , its init function is called only once. Next time the modal is shown, the init function is not triggered.

Is there any way to fix this. I know the issue is basically because its closed via jquery as `$('#msg-modal').modal('hide');` , which actually hides the element but not close it

Comment: Can't the modal be dismissed/closed or does it have to be hidden?

Comment: @rrd " `<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"> &times; </button>` is there to dismiss , i think. Its not helping me :(

Comment: Try the answer @esquarial provided, then you can use $onInit() in the controller which fires once upon instantiation.

Comment: @ShashankVivek please include a JSFiddle demo with the issue, so that you will get the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an ng-if in the controller line and set it to false when the modal needs to be closed and true when the modal needs to be open the controller will reinitialize.

I am assumming you are using ng-include and the controller together. so the line will be.

```
<div ng-include="modal_data.template" ng-if="toggle"></div>
```

then when you use the open function add.

```
$('#msg-modal').modal();
$scope.toggle=true;
```

when you close the modal you use.

```
$('#msg-modal').modal('hide');
$scope.toggle=false;
```

Comment: I used `ng-if="toggle"` at the `ng-controller` div of template, and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this   `$('#msg-modal').modal('destroy').remove()`

This will destroy the modal and then remove the div that was "hosting" the modal completely from the DOM

Comment: TypeError: data[option] is not a function